# Java- why is my for loop only displaying the last element added to the ArrayList?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a simple 'Shopping Basket' program in Java, and can currently add items and their prices to the basket. I now want to add the functionality to display the entire contents of the basket, but seem to be going wrong somewhere...

I have a `menu()` method, defined in the class `Program.java`, which is what is 'driving' the program:

```
public static void menu() {
    System.out.println("Press 1 to add an item to the basket. ");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to remove an item from the basket. ");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to display the basket contents. ");
    System.out.println("Press 9 to proceed to checkout. ");
    System.out.println("Press 0 to exit program");
    menuSelection = kb.nextInt();
    
    if(menuSelection == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the item: ");
        item.name = kb.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the price of the item: ");
        item.price = kb.nextDouble();
        basket.addItemToBasket(item);
    } else if(menuSelection == 2) {
        System.out.println("Which item would you like to remove? ");
        item.name = kb.nextLine();
        //basket.removeItemFromBasket(item);
        basket.removeItemFromBasket(item);
    } else if (menuSelection == 3) {
        basket.displayBasket();
    } else if(menuSelection == 9) {
        System.out.println("Proceed to checkout");
    } else if(menuSelection == 0) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I am currently working on the method `displayBasket()`, which is defined in the `Basket.java` class, and should display the entire contents of the basket.

It is currently defined with:

```
public void displayBasket() {
    //return basket.toString();
    int i = 0;
    //while(i < basket.size()) {
    //  System.out.println(basket.get(i).name);
    //  i++;
    //}
    
    for(Item itm : basket) {
        System.out.println(itm.name);
    }
}
```

The `addItemToBasket()` method is also defined in `Basket.java` with:

```
public void addItemToBasket(Item item) {
    basket.add(item);
    Program.menu();
}
```

but I'm clearly doing something wrong with the loop here, as whenever I select the option that calls this method, it just prints out the item that was last added to the list for the total number of items in the list.

For example, if I add "bread", "milk" & "coffee" to the list, with their prices, and then choose option 3 from the menu, to display the contents of the basket, I get the output:

> coffee
>
> coffee
>
> coffee

Why is this? What am I doing that's causing my loop

Comment: TL;DR: You need `new` to create new objects. Putting the same object 3 times in the list is going to end up like this.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks. So I changed my `add()` method to add a new item: `basket.add(new Item());`, but when I now try to call the `displayBasket()` method, the program seems to stop running... i.e. after I select that option from the menu, nothing happens... any idea why?

Comment: Probably something resulting in an empty basket or so. You can pepper `System.out` statements to follow the execution of the program, display amount of items in the basket etc. (if you don't have / know how to use a debugger). Your `addItemToBasket` method is also questionable. It shouldn't call `Program.menu()` and without that call there's no need for it.

Comment: Without the call to `Program.menu()`, the Program exits after adding an item to the list...

Comment: It shouldn't do that. You should have a loop where the menu is displayed, if "exit" is selected you can break out of the loop, otherwise you perform the operation, come back to the loop, the menu is displayed again etc.